# Remainder from a functional CLT

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, stochastic-calculus

**Setting**:

Say we have a sequence of random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1...n}$ such that for $T_n(s)=n^{\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{[sn]}X_i$ we have $$T_n(s)\Rightarrow W(s)$$
as $n\to\infty$.

**Question**:

Is there an result as to how does the following limit looks like $$n^{\alpha}\left(T_n(s)-W(s)\right)$$
as $n\to\infty$? (Note that I would essentially need an $O_p(1)$ limit.)

Thanks for your comments and/or references in advance :-)